# Can migrate with models.DateTimeField() but SQL Error with models.TimeField()

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a Django model that is not working properly. When I migrate the following, I don't get any errors and I get an `id`, `question_text`, and `time` column in my database:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

But if I change the `models.DateTimeField()` to `models.TimeField()`, I can successfuly run `python3 manage.py makemigrations`:

```
Migrations for 'app':
  app/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Question
```

But when I then try to run `python3 manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0002_question_time...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT '22:12:07.640513' NOT NULL' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 44, in add_field
    super().add_field(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 447, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) DEFAULT '22:12:07.640513' NOT NULL' at line 1")
```

This error happens EVEN IF I reverse all the migrations (either manually or with `python3 manage.py migrate app zero`), delete the migration files, and skip to step 2 (which is just starting with the `models.TimeField`). Does anyone know why this is? I've included my migration file for reference:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.10 on 2021-06-17 22:16

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Question',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('question_text', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('time', models.TimeField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

This is the result of `python3 manage.py sqlmigrate app 0001`

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model User
--
CREATE TABLE `app_user` (`phone_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL);
--
-- Create model Question
--
CREATE TABLE `app_question` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `question_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `question_text` varchar(200) NOT NULL, `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL, `time` time(6) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE `app_question_users` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `question_id` integer NOT NULL, `user_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE `app_question` ADD CONSTRAINT `app_question_question_text_time_d3def135_uniq` UNIQUE (`question_text`, `time`);
ALTER TABLE `app_question_users` ADD CONSTRAINT `app_question_users_question_id_9a89887c_fk_app_question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `app_question` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `app_question_users` ADD CONSTRAINT `app_question_users_user_id_043c67c7_fk_app_user_phone_number` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `app_user` (`phone_number`);
ALTER TABLE `app_question_users` ADD CONSTRAINT `app_question_users_question_id_user_id_04063864_uniq` UNIQUE (`question_id`, `user_id`);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect the generated SQL using the command:

`python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_name> <migration_file_number>`.

Sometimes, I'm running this and execute the SQL on a separate SQL client to get more information regarding the errors.

Comment: I edited myu post to show what SQL is being run.